# Вывод блока в 30% от ширины странички

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать на страничке вывод товаров блоками, по три в ряд. и все бы хорошо, все сделал. вышло так как нужно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть одна проблема. Если товаров столько сколько нужно чтоб каждый товар был в ряд по три штуки, все хорошо, но если одному ряду не хватает товара, или двух, то товар заполняет весь ряд. И выходит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом сделать чтобы каждый из товаров занимал только свое пространство, так же как и если они в одном ряду из трех товаров?
Буду благодарен за помощь!

```css
#orange_zone {
  background-color: #fbb400;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 25px 50px 25px 50px;
}
.case_news {
  display: table;
  margin-top: 13px;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 15px 10px;
}
#case_case_case {
  display: table;
  margin-top: 13px;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 15px 10px;
}
#case_news_info {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 27%;
  margin: 10px;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
}
.title_news {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.content_news {
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.content_news2 {
  line-height: 20px;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
}
.content_news2 img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.footer_news {
  border-top: 2px solid #fbb400;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.footer_news2 {
  border-top: 2px solid #fbb400;
  padding: 10px;
}
a.buttom_look {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  /*margin-top: 25px;*/
  display: block;
  background-color: #fbb400;
  color: #fff;
}
a.buttom_look:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f4b108;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="orange_zone">

  <div id="case_case_case">
    <div class="case_news">
      <div id="case_news_info">
        <div class="head_news">
          <div class="content_news2">
            <img src="/gallery/photos_soh/7/56f92407fa55571c6a7bc384796d370c.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_news2">
          <div class="detal_med">
            <div class="title_ded_med">dfvbdfbff</div>
            fvdfb dfb d</div>
          <div class="look_more">
            <a href="/" class="buttom_look">1000$</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="case_news_info">
        <div class="head_news">
          <div class="content_news2">
            <img src="/gallery/photos_soh/6/qww.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_news2">
          <div class="detal_med">
            <div class="title_ded_med">Супер мед</div>
            Очень хороший мед</div>
          <div class="look_more">
            <a href="/" class="buttom_look">70$</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="case_news_info">
        <div class="head_news">
          <div class="content_news2">
            <img src="/gallery/photos_soh/5/qww.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_news2">
          <div class="detal_med">
            <div class="title_ded_med">Lime honey 15</div>
            Бла бла бла</div>
          <div class="look_more">
            <a href="/" class="buttom_look">100$</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="case_case_case">
    <div class="case_news">
      <div id="case_news_info">
        <div class="head_news">
          <div class="content_news2">
            <img src="/gallery/photos_soh/4/med.png" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_news2">
          <div class="detal_med">
            <div class="title_ded_med">Lime honey 10</div>
            vintage 2016</div>
          <div class="look_more">
            <a href="/" class="buttom_look">100$</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="case_news_info">
        <div class="head_news">
          <div class="content_news2">
            <img src="/gallery/photos_soh/3/mmd1.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_news2">
          <div class="detal_med">
            <div class="title_ded_med">Lime honey 3</div>
            vintage 2016</div>
          <div class="look_more">
            <a href="/" class="buttom_look">100$</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="case_news_info">
        <div class="head_news">
          <div class="content_news2">
            <img src="/gallery/photos_soh/2/med.png" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_news2">
          <div class="detal_med">
            <div class="title_ded_med">Пчела-матка 10</div>
          </div>
          <div class="look_more">
            <a href="/" class="buttom_look">100$</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="case_case_case">
    <div class="case_news">
      <div id="case_news_info">
        <div class="head_news">
          <div class="content_news2">
            <img src="/gallery/photos_soh/1/med.png" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_news2">
          <div class="detal_med">
            <div class="title_ded_med">Классный мед</div>
            Покупай не пожалеешь</div>
          <div class="look_more">
            <a href="/" class="buttom_look">100$</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- orange_zone !-->
```

Comment: как-то слишком много элементов используют один и тот же `id`. В принципе браузер даже не гарантирует, что стили применятся к любом элементу кроме одного среди имеющих одинаковый `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Блоки сами центрируются**

```css
.in{
text-align:center;
width:90%;
border:2px solid gray;
background:silver;
box-shadow:0 0 10pt #727272;
padding:10pt;
border-radius:4pt;}
.block{
margin:10pt;
padding:10pt;
border:2px solid red;
border-radius:4pt;
width:200px;
height:100px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<div class="in"> 
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>

</div>
```

> http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/dXApNK?editors=110

Comment: нельзя ли это как-то в мой css применить?

Comment: смотри - мои блоки - это будет обёртка , стили изменишь только для блока с img и для блока с описанием , работы не много

Comment: щас проверь ссылку в оранжевом поле

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 5%;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 1.666%;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Блок 1
</div><div>
  Блок 2
</div><div>
  Блок 3
</div><div>
  Блок 4
</div><div>
  Блок 5
</div><div>
  Блок 6
</div><div>
  Блок 7
</div>
```

Comment: нельзя ли это как-то в мой css применить?

Comment: @Денис, к сожалению, мне лень его читать... Попробуй составить [mcve], тогда подумаю.